# Как вывести классы для элементов меню wp_get_nav_menu_items()?

Tags: php, wordpress

подскажите пожалуйста как мне вывести классы меню элементов которые я указывал в админ панели

```
if( $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items('Главный tabbar') ) { // "Главный tabbar"
    $menu_list = '';
        foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
        $title = $menu_item->title; // заголовок элемента меню (анкор ссылки)
        $url = $menu_item->url; // URL ссылки
        $classes = $menu_item->classes; // Вывод классов
        $active_icon = ( $menu_item->object_id == get_queried_object_id() ) ? 'fas' : 'fal'; // Определение активной иконки fontawesome
        $current = ( $menu_item->object_id == get_queried_object_id() ) ? 'aria-current="page"' : ''; // Определение текущей страницы
        $menu_list .= '<a href="' . $url . '" class="' . $active_icon . ' ' . $classes . '" ' . $current . '><span>' . $title . '</span></a>';
    }
    echo $menu_list;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> К сожалению $classes = $menu_item->classes; выводит только Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы вывести классы используйте:

```
echo implode( ' ', $menu_item->classes )
```

Но лучше перепишите ваш код на Walker, то совсем плохо выглядет)

Comment: Вывел таким вот образом $classes = $menu_item->classes[0];

Comment: echo implode( ' ', $menu_item->classes ) чем лучше чем мой варинт? $classes = $menu_item->classes[0]

Comment: если у тебя будет больше 1-го класса, то это не будет работать нормально)

Comment: А если у меня только один класс echo implode( ' ', $menu_item->classes ) — этот вариант не будет нести лишней нагрузки в запросе?

Comment: Нагрузка настолько мала, что вы даже не почувствуете)